# swift- Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type '[_]'

Tags: swift, generics, swift-extensions

I'm trying to implement a zip function as an extension to Array, and I'm intending for it to be used like this:

```
let myKeys = ["a","b","c"]
let myVars = [1,2,3]
myKeys.zip(myVars) // ["a":1,"b":2,"c":3]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
extension Array {
    public func zip<T,U>(vals: [U]) -> [T:U] {

        var dict: [T:U] = Dictionary()

        for (i,key) in self.enumerate() {
            if let k = key as? T {
                dict[k] = vals[i]
            }
        }

        return dict
    }
}

let myKeys = ["a","b","c"]
let myVars = [1,2,3]
myKeys.zip(myVars) // ERROR: Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type '[_]'
```

On the last line I am getting an error that I do not completely understand. I understand it to mean that I'm passing an [Int] and it's expecting an [_]. But isn't _ just a generic placeholder here? Why would it complain about receiving an [Int]?

Also, if I implement zip as a class function it has no issues:

```
class func zip<T,U>(keys keys: [T], vals: [U]) -> [T:U] {

    var dict: [T:U] = Dictionary()

    for (i,key) in keys.enumerate() {
        dict[key] = vals[i]
    }

    return dict
}

zip(keys: myKeys,vals: myVals) // ["a":1,"b":2,"c":3]
```

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Array` already has an associated type, it's called `Element`, so no need to declare `T`. The problem with your code is that you cannot really convert an `Element` to undefined type `T` (there is no connection between `T` and the array element type).

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    public func zip<U>(vals: [U]) -> [Element: U] {

        var dict: [Element: U] = Dictionary()

        for (i, key) in self.enumerate() {
            dict[key] = vals[i]
        }

        return dict
    }
}

let myKeys = ["a","b","c"]
let myVars = [1,2,3]
let map = myKeys.zip(myVars)

print(map)
```

Also note that I have added `Hashable` requirement for the keys.