# Swift templates

Tags: swift, templates

I have a template class for an array datasource which looks like this:

```
class ArrayTableViewDataSource<T>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let configureCell:      ((cell: UITableViewCell, item: T)->())?
    private var items:              [T]?
    private let reuseIdentifier:    String


    required init(items: [T]?, reuseIdentifier: String, configureCell: ((cell: UITableViewCell, item: T)->())?) {
        self.items = items
        self.configureCell = configureCell
        self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
        super.init()
    }
...
}
```

In my test case (first use of function), I try to test the class a bit by creating a test class like so:

```
        let testObject = ArrayTableViewDataSource(items: items, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, configureCell: {
                                                (cell, item) in
        //Some test
    })
```

Problem is that I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type '[_]?'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36553959/5654848). It should help you.

Comment: An array contains a generic type element that they try to redefine or access under a different name (if I understand the question correctly). UITableViewDataSource does not contain a Generic type? I do not understand the connection between my question and the one referenced

Comment: Weirdly enough, after fiddling around a bit, the code now compiles fine. I have experienced this problem once before though with the same result where fiddling seems to have resolved it.